# When I am appending every string to .txt file by using try String(contentsOf: shareLog) in swift failing Some times

Tags: ios, swift, file-manager, filehandler

I am calling bellow function to get contentsof the .txt file and I am getting successfully some times but some times when I am trying to get It Is going to catch block and giving the bellow error ..please help me out

// Used for sharing

```
func getLogData(file: String) -> String? {

    let shareLog = dir.appendingPathComponent(file, isDirectory: false)

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: shareLog.path) {
        do {
            let result1 = try String(contentsOf: shareLog)
            print(result1)
            return result1
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed reading from file: \(error)")
            return nil
        }

    }

    print("Failed to get log at: \(logPath)")
    return nil
}
```

//Error when try to get .txt file contentsof

**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 "The file “somelog-log.txt” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/199D8E4D-6DFC-4327-BC57-06957BCC6EA3/Documents/somelog-log.txt}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the encoding explicitly

```
let result1 = try String(contentsOf: shareLog, encoding: .utf8)
```

Comment: Thanks for that but when I did this .. I am getting ..... Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file “2018-04-04T15/28/48-04/00-log.txt” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0B8CE9C6-AAF2-41C1-9FA4-65FB57BD4B4E/Documents/2018-04-04T15:28:48-04:00-log.txt, NSStringEncoding=4}

Comment: Save the file always as UTF8.

Comment: I am not saving i am sharing .txt file through email.. So when I am reading the file contents it is failing with that error.

Comment: You are reading the file from disk so sometime it must have been written to disk. Make sure that the encoding can be determined.

Comment: txt.appendLineToURL(fileURL: logPath as URL)  ..   
     extension String { //1st method  
    func appendLineToURL(fileURL: URL) throws {
        do {
            try (self + "\n").appendToURL(fileURL: fileURL)
        }catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    //2nd method
    func appendToURL(fileURL: URL) throws {
        let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        do {
            try data.append(fileURL: fileURL)
        }catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
}

Comment: And then used this for appending....extension Data {
    func append(fileURL: URL) throws {
        if let fileHandle  = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileURL.path) {  
            defer {
                fileHandle.closeFile()
            }
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.write(self)
            fileHandle.closeFile()
        }
        else {
            do {
                 try write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                print("")
            }catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Thanks for all your help.. I figure it out answer, my strings are coming as Ascii or UtF8 so I have to use both encoding techniques to read contents of file.